# Accessing a variable from another file

Tags: swift, file

I have two files. One that has this class inside of it:

```
class RelativeStrength: NSObject {

    func calculateRSI() {
        let relativeStrength1 = 87652
        let relativeStrength2 = 5634

        let rSI1 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength1 + 456))
        let rSI2 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength2 + 12))

        let average = (rSI1 + rSI2) / 2      
    }
}
```

And another one where I'd like to access `average` to use it in other calculations. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have `average` be a static variable inside your `RelativeStrength` class.

```
class RelativeStrength: NSObject {
    static var average: Double = 0

    func calculateRSI() {
        let relativeStrength1 = 87652
        let relativeStrength2 = 5634

        let rSI1 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength1 + 456))
        let rSI2 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength2 + 12))

        average = (rSI1 + rSI2) / 2      
    }
}
```

Then in your other class, you can reference that average directly:

```
class OtherClass: NSObject {
    var randomVar = 0

    func setRandomVar() {
        randomVar = RelativeStrength.average
    }
}
```

If you want your `calculateRSI` function to be used in your other class as well, then you can just add `static` to the function name, and use it the same way.

Comment: This seems to be the perfect method! But I get `Expected declaration` at `randomVar = RelativeStrength.average`

Comment: Be careful.  If you use this method although you can have multiple instances of the RelativeStrength class they will all be sharing the same average variable.

Comment: @Martin33000 Sorry for being unclear. The code was just an example. You obviously need to write code in methods/functions only. Check my updated example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! No more errors, the only issue is that I already have a class declared in the file where I will use `average`. Now I need to transfert it again from `OtherClass` to the class already there.. Haha!

Comment: I gladly accepted your answer, could you tell me why `randomVar` stays at 0 even after `randomVar = RelativeStrength.average`? Do I need to call `setRandomVar()` ?

Comment: @Martin33000 You need to call `calculateRSI()` first, otherwise `average` is never set. Then, to set `randomVar`, yes, you need to call `setRandomVar()`.

Comment: Where can I call `setRandomVar()`? It seems that wherever I call it it's before `calculateRSI()` so `randomVar` stays 0

Comment: `randomVar` is the first thing printed in the console which means it is really called before `average` by the way

Comment: @Martin33000 Sorry, I am kind of confused. Is `calculateRSI()` automatically called?

Comment: Yes it is in `viewDidLoad` as soon as the app is launched. I then tried `OtherClass().setRandomVar()` in a function I use to refresh the data to make sure it is called after `calculateRSI()` but still, `randomVar` won't update to `average` after refreshing...

Comment: By the way I had to put `RelativeStrength.average = (rSI1 + rSI2) / 2` instead of just `average = (rSI1 + rSI2) / 2` to get rid of `Static member 'average' cannot be used on instance of type 'RelativeStrength'` maybe this has something to do with the problem?

Comment: @Martin33000 No, it has nothing to do with the problem. Hmm... so you're positive that `calculateRSI()` is called before `setRandomVar()`?

Comment: I moved `calculateRSI()` to `willFinishLaunching` and left `setRandomVar()` in my `MainController`'s `viewDidLoad`. Now the console prints everything in order but `randomVar` is still 0

Comment: Actually when I print `RelativeStrength.average` inside `setRandomVar()` to see if it has a value it also prints 0 when I call the function...

Comment: I added another function inside `OtherClass` that just adds `1+2`, when I call it it prints `3` so I believe the problem comes from `RelativeStrenght`

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside `calculateRSI()`, and check the value of `(rSI1 + rSI2) / 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a computed property instead. The only difference with compute properties is that for this kind of reasons they look neater.

```
class RelativeStrength: NSObject {
    var rsi: Int {
      let relativeStrength1 = 87652
      let relativeStrength2 = 5634

      let rSI1 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength1 + 456))
      let rSI2 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength2 + 12))

      return (rSI1 + rSI2) / 2
    }
}
```

And then:

```
let average = RelativeStrength().rsi
print(average)
```

Here is an example in a playground:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Rafael it works amazingly well where I need to reuse average but the problem is that I used `calculateRSI()` in a viewDidLoad, when I replace ``calculateRSI()`` with `rsi` I get `Expression of type 'Double' is unused`

Comment: @Martin33000 what does calculateRSI() do currently in the viewDidLoad? As I see your function seems to do nothing because is neither setting a class attribute nor is returning the value?

Comment: I kind of simplified the function for the example. But here is what I have in my viewDidLoad: `fetchRsiData() { items, error in
            guard let items = items,
                error == nil else {
                    print(error ?? "Unknown error")
                    return
            }
            let otherObject = RelativeStrength()
            otherObject.items = items
            otherObject.calculateRSI()
        }`

Comment: Then there is no reason to use `otherObject.calculateRSI()` anymore since the "calculation" of RSI is done on the fly (automatically) everytime you call the `.rsi` computed property (as far as I can understand).

Comment: Let me try without it. Could you tell me how `fetchRsiData` would be like in your opinion?

Comment: I can't really understand the context of your program because I have a very minimal version of it, but I suspect that you just need to remove the line `otherObject.calculateRSI()` from `fetchRsiData` because you don't need to calculate manually the RSI value, you now have a computed property that does the calculation every time you want to access it.

Comment: I recommend to have a look at this post http://computingstories.com/swift%20stories/swift-computed-property.html if you are not familiar with computed properties, they are quite powerful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience Rafael, you already taught me a lot! I think I removed to much code from my example, there is more stuff that make it impossible to replace `calculateRSI()` I guess...

Answer (score -1):

```
class RelativeStrength: NSObject {

    func calculateRSI() -> CGFloat {
        let relativeStrength1 = 87652
        let relativeStrength2 = 5634

        let rSI1 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength1 + 456))
        let rSI2 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength2 + 12))

        let average = (rSI1 + rSI2) / 2  

        return average
    }
}


class OtherClass: NSObject {

    let average = RelativeStrength().calculateRSI()
    print(average)
}
```

Or you can use delegates

```
protocol InformingDelegate {
    func averageChanged(average: CGFloat)
}

class RelativeStrength: NSObject {

func calculateRSI() {

    var delegate = InformingDelegate?

    let relativeStrength1 = 87652
    let relativeStrength2 = 5634

    let rSI1 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength1 + 456))
    let rSI2 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength2 + 12))

    let average = (rSI1 + rSI2) / 2  

    delegate?.averageChanged(average: average)

}

class OtherClass: NSObject, InformingDelegate {

    func averageChanged(average: CGFloat) {
        print(average)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I get `Constant 'average' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected` and then `Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type '()' and 'Int'` when I try to use it..

Comment: The first idea is a solution although you are still not accessing a variable.  Using delegates is more than is needed for this situation and you need to assign your delegate to an instance of the RelativeString class.  Also a delegate isn't used for accessing the value as such but being informed when something happens.